# Custom slider iOS objective-c (Increase Height of Horizontal Slider and Add Image on Thumb)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to implement custom slider

[image]

i tried a lot and get this  https://github.com/jane/JaneSliderControl but is not in objective-c.Can anyone help for creating custom slider

Comment: It may be in Swift but it can be used in Objective C as well.

Comment: Have a look at this for using swift into Objective-c project https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-can-i-import-swift-code-to-objective-c

Comment: Thanks Nitish  for Reply

Comment: Can I get other Third party link which is similiar to my need?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need a UISlider with value on the handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41257612/i-need-a-uislider-with-value-on-the-handle)

Comment: @videh-jaiswal : I have added a duplicate question link, I had answered a similar question long back, that should help you get what you wanna achieve

Comment: Have a look on this link https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=slider

Comment: hii Sandeep Thanks for Reply

Comment: Sandeep can u tell me how i increase height of horizontal bar of uislider and add image on Thumb?

Comment: i already see this  cocoacontrols.com/search?q=slider  and lots of link

Comment: but not get how to increase Height and add image

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create your own custom UI, why don't you try a very handy tools like [PaintCode](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/).

With PaintCode, you can create any custom UIs without any hurdles. After creating custom UIs in PaintCode, you can generate code in Objective-C, Swift as per your requirement and embed in your project.

Here are some of the tutorials to start with PaintCode.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/92972/paintcode-tutorial-for-developers-getting-started
https://www.raywenderlich.com/97941/paintcode-swift-tutorial-part-2-custom-progress-bar
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4jovZyBMdrQ (sample slider using paintcode)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yweBm-UpId4